# Ruby File.exist syntax error

Tags: ruby, bash

I am trying to check the presence of the file with below command ,but it's throwing this syntax error, can someone please help me on what am I missing

```
system("File.exist?(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh)")
```

Error

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
sh: -c: line 0: `File.exist?(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh)'
```

Comment: What is the `system("    ")` supposed to do around your expression? You are sending that string to the shell, but it's supposed to be executed as Ruby code, no?

Comment: And you are missing the quotes. `File.exist?("/Library/......")`

Comment: new command ```system("File.exist?(\"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh\")")```   new error ```sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"'
sh: -c: line 0: `File.exist?("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh")'```

Comment: Of course it doesn't work... Again: Why is there a `system(" ")` around the whole thing?

Comment: This makes no sense. Why is `system` involved here? Don't use that. It's the wrong tool. Did you read the manual on what that function does before randomly trying things?

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to see if a file exists:

```
file = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
File.exist?(file)
```

Presumably you want to do something with this file other than test that it exists, like run it:

```
if (File.exist?(file))
  system(file)
end
```

Comment: thank you ,  now I got my mistake . this resolves my issue

Comment: The parentheses around `File.exist?(file)` look a bit odd.

Comment: @Stefan They're optional but allowed. JavaScript, C++ and many others require them so I tend to put those in there to avoid ambiguity.